# decimal getting truncated in tsql

Tags: html, t-sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Im new to coldfusion and tsql, so if this is a silly mistake, I am sorry for wasting your time. I have searched for "decimal truncation, tsql, cold fusion". And any of those in combination.

I have a form that submits a decimal, yet the DB is recording the data as an integer. Meaning, the form has the value of 2.2, the DB stores 2.

The column specs per my DB editor:

```
COLUMN_NAME      DATA_TYPE   DATA_PRECISION  DATA_SCALE  NULLABLE  DATA_DEFAULT 
promofactor      decimal          15              5           NO        ((0))
```

The HTML form:

`<input type="number" name="promoFactor" class="form-control" id="promoFactor" placeholder="Must be a number" required step="0.0001">`

The cold fusion query:

```
DECLARE @promofactor decimal(15,5)  = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_decimal"  value="#form.promoFactor#"/>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for `cf_sql_decimal` cfsqltypes, you have to supply the `scale` attribute to cfqueryparam.

If you want 5 decimal places:

```
<cfqueryparam type="cf_sql_decimal" value="#form.promofactor#" scale="5" />
```

docs: https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam

Comment: THANKS! Are there any other `cfqueryparam` types that accept something addition like this?

Comment: @davidhartman00 `cf_sql_numeric` also accepts scale. Other useful attributes are in the docs linked in the answer. `list="true"` is handy when doing something that requires an IN() statement.